# Upload em submit form AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho um formulário onde envio dados através do AJAX jQuery.
Porém, eu também gostaria de enviar um arquivo. Como faço para adicionar ao meu código?

```
var formData = {
    'titulo': $('input[name=titulo]').val(),
    'tipo'  : $('select[name=tipo]').val(),
    'dataa' : $('input[name=data]').val(),
    'desc'  : $('textarea[name=desc]').val()
};

// process the form
$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'processar.php',
    data        : formData,
    dataType    : 'json',
    encode      : true
})
```

Comment: Nenhuma [dessas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bajax%5D+upload) perguntas resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia tentar algo como :

**HTML**

```
<h1>jQuery Ajax submit Multipart form</h1>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
    <input type="text" name="extraField"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="file" name="files"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="file" name="files"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>

<h1>Ajax Post Result</h1>
<span id="result"></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {

        //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get form
        var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

        // Create an FormData object
        var data = new FormData(form);

        // If you want to add an extra field for the FormData
        data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");

        // disabled the submit button
        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: "/api/upload/multi",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {

                $("#result").text(data);
                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);

            },
            error: function (e) {

                $("#result").text(e.responseText);
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);

            }
        });

    });

});
```

Source : https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-submit-a-multipart-form/

O segredo aqui é usar **new FormData()** para "recuperar os dados do formulário" e setar o parametro **processData** da requisição ajax para **FALSE**.